# Unable to estimate xmin, alpha for large dataset using PoweRlaw

Tags: r, power-law

I have the following are the sample data set. The first column is the serial number and column 2 is data.

Using R, I'm trying to find the xmin, alpha and pvalue. The above data set is discrete, the values are large and treating the data as continuous. For some reason R is not able give proper output for `est= estimate_xmin()`. Here is the same code.

```
> library('poweRlaw')
> m_bl = conpl$new(sample_data$V1)
> est = estimate_xmin(m_bl)
> m_bl$setXmin(est)
Warning message:
In min(which(internal[["dat"]] >= (x - .Machine$double.eps^0.5))) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 
> est
$KS
[1] Inf

$xmin
[1] NA

$pars
[1] NA

attr(,"class")
[1] "estimate_xmin"
>
```

Please let me know if Im missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`estimate_xmin` has an optional argument `xmax`:

> estimate_xmin(m, xmins = NULL, pars = NULL, xmax = 1e+05)

From the documentation:

> To speed up computations for discrete distributions it is sensible to
>   put an upper bound, i.e. xmax or explicitly give values of where to
>   search, i.e. xmin.

Since the minimum value in your sample is larger than the default value of xmax
, `estimate_xmin`
can't find xmin, unless the upper bound `xmax` is increased suffiently:

```
> library('poweRlaw')

> m_bl = conpl$new(sample_data$V1)

> #==========================================
> est = estimate_xmin(m_bl)  

> m_bl$setXmin(est)
Warning in min(which(internal[["dat"]] >= (x - .Machine$double.eps^0.5))) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

> #------------------------------------------
> est = estimate_xmin(m_bl,xmax=3e+5)  

> m_bl$setXmin(est)
Warning in min(which(internal[["dat"]] >= (x - .Machine$double.eps^0.5))) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

> #------------------------------------------
> est = estimate_xmin(m_bl,xmax=5e+5)  

> m_bl$setXmin(est)

> #------------------------------------------
> est = estimate_xmin(m_bl,xmax=Inf)  

> m_bl$setXmin(est)

> #==========================================
> m_bl
Reference class object of class "conpl"
Field "xmin": 
[1] 11082439
Field "pars": 
[1] 15.83368
Field "no_pars": 
[1] 1
```

Comment: I've added a note on the github website and I'll try and fix for the next release. Thanks